# resource relationship tracking in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

My business use case has a specific parent-child model relationship.The structure looks like this approx.

-Parent-1
    -Child-11
    -Child-12
          -property-121
          -property-122

-Parent-2
    -Child-21
    -Child-22
          -property-121
          -property-122

Parent has a child.A child can have properties.

My question is ,how do i send the data to the ga by using ga.js/analytics.js, so that i can get the following report.

1.Find all the parents who has child2 with property2.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you are looking for, but if parent-child hierachies are sufficient (i.e. if you do not need the hierachy between the children) you could record your relations as transactions with the parent identifier as transaction id and the children as products. For properties you'd add custom dimensions to the children/products.

To find a parent with a specific child you would filter the transaction reports by product identifier (i.e. show transaction id where product is [your child id]).

Another way that would cover multiple hierachy levels would be to record the relations as virtual pageviews with an url structure like /parent/child1/child2/child3. The behaviour/content drilldown report would allow you to quickly examine any parent for the children you're looking for. Childrens properties could be stored in the "page title" field for filtering by property.